# Using different activities for different views in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I am developing a Music Player and I have a view flipper to control all the artist view, album view, so on and so forth. What I am doing now is that I have list view in each view of the view flipper. However, I do not want to put all my codes inside one activity but rather, to have different activities for each view. Is that possible to implement?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is just to create the same user experience provided by `ViewFlipper` you'd be better off using `overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)` which has been available since API Level 5.

You'd call `overridePendingTransition` in whatever event was causing the activity to change. An example can be found within the [Android SDK samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html), but I provide one below to more fully answer your question.

First you must define your animations. Create a folder `anim` under `res`. Then define two transistions one *in* and one *out*.

in_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

out_left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

Then in the event which is starting the other activity you'd use these animations in your call to `overridePendingTransition`.

```
// this code snippet does not show wiring event to button
void buttonClicked() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, HistoryListActivity_.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_right, R.anim.out_left);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, I do not want to put all my
>   codes inside one activity but rather,
>   to have different activities for each
>   view.

Please don't do this. Not only is it not possible, but the other place where this is sorta supported (`TabHost`), it wastes RAM and CPU.